# Is there anyway to add the Mic icon to the Swype keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, ios

I really like the 3rd party Swype keyboard, but it is missing the Mic button.  Is there a gesture or something to engage the Siri Microphone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is currently not possible due to restrictions with 3rd-party keyboards in iOS.

From [Apple site:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html)

> Custom keyboards, like all app extensions in iOS 8.0, have no access to the device microphone, so dictation input is not possible.